# Aqueous electrons in electrochemical cells

Tags: electrochemistry, redox, electrons

In the context of a zinc-copper electrochemical cell, zinc atoms at the anode are oxidized, releasing electrons and forming zinc ions that dissolve into the solution ($\ce{Zn(s) -> Zn^{2+}(aq) + 2e-}$). This process leaves electrons behind on the electrode. Given the high reactivity of electrons, it's intriguing that they don't also "dissolve" into the aqueous solution like the zinc ions. Considering the potential for radical formation if electrons were to interact with the solution, how is it that electrons are prevented from entering the solution? Is this just a case of textbooks leaving out a loose thread in the story of electrochemical cells?

As a side-note, I can imagine a metal plate under water onto which ultraviolet light is shone. I would guess that surface electrons could absorb the light and become free in the water. So I don't see why would a similar effect not sometimes occur from the bombardment of the electrode surfaces by molecules (rather than light) in the electrochemical solutions?

Comment: Zinc doesn't simply release electrons. This process is endothermic. The first and second ionization energy is 9.4 eV and 18.0 eV, respectively.

Comment: If zinc does not release electrons in water, alkaline metals can, but these electrons reacts immediately with water according to :  $\ce{2 e- + 2 H2O -> 2 OH- + H2}$

Comment: Forming aqueous electrons is energetically highly disadvantageous and occurs at  a highly negative potentials, followed in typical time scope of  hundreds of microseconds by reducing water to hydrogen. Interaction and reduction of H+(aq ) occurs at higher potential, so metals get dissolved in acids.// To the side note: Thermal energy of molecules is typically 100 times smaller than energy of photons of UV/VIS light.

Comment: Please avoid cross-posting. If you have trouble getting an answer then you might try another site.

Comment: Is there a reason for de-accepting? I see no alternate answer. I will gladly answer questions.

Answer (score 1):

Because the zinc in your example is the anode, the electrons are actually not released into the elecrtolyte. They are pulled through the external circuit to the cathode, in your case copper, and it is the cathode that releases the electrons into the electrolyte.

In the case of a water-based electrolyte the electrons do not get very far before they react with the water to form hydrogen gas, or perhaps with metal ions in the electrolyte (including, possibly, zinc ions coming from the anode) to reduce and deposit the metal. Liquid ammonia solutions, on the other hand, are less reactive towards electrons. They are often used as media for electrolytically generating blue-colored solvated electrons in solution.

Comment: To the first part, disconnect the two halves of the cell so we have just zinc (or copper if you prefer) in a solution. In equilibrium there will be atoms leaving the electrode and returning to it at the same rate. Do they leave electrons behind when they do so?

Comment: @Kris hard to answer. Atoms of metallic elements dissolced into water are likely to react, releasing hydrogen, possibly even before the electrons would have become solvated.